# start and stop button in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hey guys I am developing one app in which i run while lop in asycTask on click of button and i want to stop that task on click of other button like start and stop but problem is as soon as while loop starts it does not listen for any other event as if blocking ui thread what should i do?

Comment: WHat purpose is to run while loop? An it is not blocking the ui thread but thread of AsyncTask.

Comment: hi vladimir i have given code please check

Answer (score 3):

You need to check [isCancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) to find out if your `AsyncTask` has been cancelled.

In your while loop :

```
if (isCancelled()) {
    break;
}
```

That way you aren't stuck in that loop indefinitely.

Comment: it does not work basically its not listening for button whle while loop is going on

Comment: What method is your while loop in?

Comment: basically while loop is inside async task and i am calling another class which i have declared seperately. i have declared object of that clas in activity and initialised it in oncreate

Comment: Which method in your custom AsyncTask is it in? It should be in `doInBackground` or a method called by `doInBackground`. Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`AsyncTask.cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. When you click the Stop button, set a boolean ivar (we'll call it isStopped) = true
2. In the onProgressUpdate function of your AsyncTask, check the status of isStopped. If it is true, break out of the while loop.

You would need to keep a reference to your Activity inside your AsyncTask to do this, so make a contructor for it that takes in an object of your Activity's type.

Comment: `isCancelled` provides the `boolean` to you, and the `while` loop is probably in `doInBackground` and not `onProgressUpdate`.

Comment: Yeah, he would have to keep a local variable and set it = isStopped inside onProgressUpdate to do what I was talking about. Didn't know your way existed. It's definitely the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you need to implement it:

Declare this in your activity so it will be available from within the OnClickListener

```
onGoingTask ex;
```

And then in your onCreate, put in this code, where startButton and stopButton are both buttons on your app

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ex.doInBackground();
        ex = new ReloadHistoryTask();
        ex.execute();
    }
});
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ex.cancel(true);
    }
});
```

Then, further down, in that same file, you'll have the declaration of your AsyncTask

```
private class onGoingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long[]> {
    @Override
    protected Long[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Long[] myCount = {0L, 0L, 0L};
        while(sflag==0) {    
            System.out.println("in while");
            //code for gps data collection
            myCount[2]++;
        }
        return myCount;
    }
}
```

I think something like that should work for you, you can take out the Long[] array if you don't need it, I just left it in there because I use it and I thought it might be handy for ya' :-)

Comment: Hi jared I have already done that but my problem is that when i click start button it starts collecting data but then it is not listening for other button click whole ui hangs while its collecting data

Comment: Do you think you can maybe post your code so I can better see what the problem is?, really, if you're just listening for GPS coordinates etc, it shouldn't require a while loop, it should be more like a LocationListener() that gets called when the data comes back.  Then, when you're done collecting data, you can call something like  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  // Remove the listener you previously added
  locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);